# Problems with bash variable expanding with single quotes

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a variable that I build like this :

```
ATTSTR=""
for file in $LOCALDIR/*.pdf
do
  ATTSTR="${ATTSTR} -a \"${file}\""
done
```

The variable now contains (notice the whitespaces in the file name) :

```
ATTSTR=' -a "/tmp/Testpage - PDFCreator.pdf"'
```

And now I want to use this variable in a command like this one :

```
mutt -s "Subject" "${ATTSTR}" recipient@example.ec
```

But it turns out that it expands like this, and thus the command fails (notice the added single quotes surrounding the expanded variable):

```
mutt -s "Subject" ' -a "/tmp/Testpage - PDFCreator.pdf"' recipient@example.ec
```

I want my variable expanded without the single quotes, using `"$ATTSTR"` or `$ATTSTR` is just worse.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Where do the single quotes come from?

Comment: Well, that's _the_ problem.

Comment: I tested this on my system, and both quoting the filename and quoting the entire string plus escape-quoting the filename work as advertised; since thi sis not reproducible it is due to some setting or translation happening on your side.

Comment: I suspect this is `IFS` related. Try unsetting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filenames are notoriously unreliable in expanded strings; resist this temptation.

Instead, use an **array** to keep the filenames intact, regardless of any whitespace:

```
arr=()
for f in $somedir/*.pdf
do
arr+=( -a "$f")
done

# and for usage/display:

mutt -s mysubject "${a[@]}" some@body
```

See the [**Bash Guide on Arrays**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but the same happens when I use an array, when expanded, single quotes appear.

Comment: This is probably due to the quoting of the filename inside the assignment, then.

Comment: @drcelus, in what context do single quotes appear? If it is in `set -x` output, don't worry about it: they appear just for your (visual) benefit, they don't affect the execution of the command.

Comment: Somehow I missed @adaptr last edit on the answer (removed double quotations from the assignment), it now works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use eval function

```
command="mutt -s \"Subject\" $ATTSTR recipient@example.ec"
response=$(eval "$command")
```