# rsync certain files, excluding the rest, ignoring .svn/ directory, recursively

Tags: networking, bash, rsync, file-sharing, regular-expressions

I'm using rsync to copy some files from a share to another.

Recursively, I need to:

- Delete files at destination that were removed from the origin
- Only sync php and js files
- Exclude every other file type
- Do not delete `.svn/` directories at destination

If I use this:

```
rsync -zavC --delete --include='*.php' --include='*.js' --exclude="*" \
    /origiin /destination
```

Then rsync is not recursive because `exclude="*"` excludes all files but also folders

If I add `--include="*/"` then the `.svn/` directory gets deleted (it also gets included)

**How can I solve this mind blasting dilemma?**

uname -a:

> Linux tux 3.9.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat May 11 20:31:08 CEST 2013
>   x86_64 GNU/Linux

rsync version:

```
rsync 3.0.9-6
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after several tries I sorted this up:

```
rsync -vaiz --delete --exclude=.svn/ --include='*.php' --include='*.js' \
    --include='*/' --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs \
    --filter "protect .svn/" /origin /destination
```

**Another approach**

in case you don't mind syncing empty dirs, just:

```
rsync -vaiz --delete --exclude=.svn/ --include='*.php' --include='*.js' \
    --include='*/' --exclude='*' /origin /destination
```

The key was to `--exclude=.svn/` before the `--include`'s

Comment: Did you hardcode these values in a bash script or generate them?  [Another --filter question using bash.](http://serverfault.com/questions/505802/rsync-not-removing-single-quotes-around-array-of-strings-filter-list)